# Как открыть сайт wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Суть такая: попросили поправить стили в CSS на сайте Wordpress. Доступа к их серверу у меня нет, поэтому нужно править у себя на локальном сервере.

Бросили мне файлы в папке wp-content.

Установил я wordpress на локальный сервер (Раньше я в Wordpress не работал), закинул туда этот файл wp-content. И вот что мне выбило

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код (197 строка):

```
<div class="bt bt-language d-none d-md-block">
                    <?php
                    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0');
                    foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value['active'] == 0) {
                            $lg = $value['language_code'];
                            $href = $value['url'];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a class="" href="<?php echo $href; ?>">
                        <span><?php echo $lg; ?></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Что нужно сделать?

Comment: У вас плагины все включены? Это функция из плагина WPML, он подключен у вас локально?

Comment: Не надо лезть в вопросы в которых не понимаешь, а клиента лучше отправить к специалисту.